# Cropping sections of an image and composing it into one image

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing

Suppose I have the following image with three equally-sized rectangles, but different letters

[image]

And I would like to combine them so that there is only one rectangle with all three rectangles layered on top of each other as such

[image]

(ignore the lines, they are just there for visual reference)

How can I do this using imagemagick's convert tool?

I have read the examples in the docs, but I think what I need to do is use `-crop` to specify the part of the image using `-geometry` with given dimensions and offset, and then use `-composite` to have it layered on top.

I'm not sure how the command would look though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution. Turns out it was quite straightforward. My image is 800x600 consisting of three 800x200 rectangles, and the goal is to extract each rectangle and layer it on one another to form an 800x200 image in the end.

First, this is the command that I use to create an empty 800x200 canvas that I will use to layer images over. Note the `^` is just a line-break for windows batch files. I think for unix shell scripts it's back slash.

```
convert -size 800x200 xc:none ^
out.png
```

Second, I update the command to add layering, which simply takes the entire image and layers it on top of my canvas

```
convert -size 800x200 xc:none ^
  image.png -composite ^
out.png
```

[image: composed]

Third, I want to be able to crop a specific portion of the image and layer it over my canvas. I use the crop command for this, but also use parentheses to performed nested operations. Since the second rectangle is at offset (0,200), that's what I crop out

```
convert -size 800x200 xc:none ^
  ( image.png -crop 800x200+0+200 ) -composite ^
out.png
```

[image]

Now that I'm able to crop and composite from one image onto another, now I just need to perform the crop and composite for all three rectangles, which is simply copy-pasting the same lines and updating the crop geometry

```
convert -size 800x200 xc:none ^
  ( image.png -crop 800x200+0+0 ) -composite ^
  ( image.png -crop 800x200+0+200 ) -composite ^
  ( image.png -crop 800x200+0+400 ) -composite ^
out.png
```

[image]